# Merge local branch into remote branch other than master?

Tags: git, github

I have a local branch A that doesn't exist yet in the remote repo. I also have a remote branch B in the remote repo. How do I merge my local changes into the remote branch?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If branch B is at local, You can merge A to B locally and push B to remote:

```
git checkout B
git merge A
git push origin B
```

If you don't have B at local, you can push A to remote and pull request to merge A to B and click `merge` button on github.

or, fetch B branch to local and merge A to B , then push B to remote, like this:

```
git checkout master
git fetch origin B:B      (fetch B to local)
git checkout B            (checkout to branch B)
git merge A               (merge A to B)
git push origin B         (push merged branch B to remote)
```

Comment: If the branch has unrelated history, then pull-request can't be created. Only way is to merge locally & then push.